# How can I generate a Mongo ObjectId in a Mongo Stitch Function?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I am trying to generate a Mongo ObjectID in a stitch function before object insertion, and keep getting errors. I've tried `const _id = ObjectId();` and also `const _id = mongoService.ObjectId()` and keep getting errors. Is it possible to generate a Mongo ObjectId in a stitch function before inserting an item in collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to generate a Mongo ObjectId in a stitch function before inserting an item in collection?

Yes, to generate a new ObjectId you can use the [BSON utility package](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/functions/utilities/#bson):

```
let id = new BSON.ObjectId();
```

You can also turn string hex to ObjectId using similar call, i.e:

```
let id = new BSON.ObjectId("5e5dd3547e96ac1963d1b841");
```

See also [Stitch: Utility Packages](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/functions/utilities/#utility-packages) for a list of utility packages provided.